# How to change git clone to other way if the folder is already downloaded manually by Shell Script?

Tags: shell-script, directory, git

I not familiar with shell script for due replace the git clone to another command,
Below is the script:

```
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv.git ~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
```

Above two link folder already downloaded:

i'm totally genius try to unzip the download folder of course this two way is not the same.

```
unzip pyenv-master.zip to ~/.pyenv
unzip pyenv-virtualenv-master.zip to ~/.pyenv
```

Could anyone give me a hand for this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use another directory name in the git clone command, e.g.

```
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv2
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv.git ~/.pyenv2/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
```

or download the packages manually:

Go to https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv and https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv, expand green **Clone or download** button on the right and hit **Download ZIP**.

Extract the files manually and copy over to `.pyenv`.

## EDIT

If you need to use git clone, you can make a condition, to do clone only if the directory doesn't exist:

```
if [ ! -d "/full/path/to/.pyenv" ]
    git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git /full/path/to/.pyenv
    git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv.git /full/path/to/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
else
    do something else
fi
```

Comment: i need to do those in shell script, i already manually download the folder but the way i do is not correct because unzip the folder into ~/.pyenv is not the same by using git clone

Comment: @Victor, see my edit, hopefully would help you

Comment: i already have those zip folder, i want to know is there anyway to put those two zip folder to ~/.pyenv by not using unzip because i have try to use unzip command to place the folder to .pyenv is totally different by using git clone but why?

Comment: what do you mean by different?

Comment: i use git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv  the folder inside .pyenv is much more than using unzip pyenv-master.zip to ~/.pyenv

Comment: I just compared the two, it's no different, the only difference is that the contents are in internal directory called `pyenv-master`. simply move everything from there to `.pyenv` and you should be good.

Comment: try to 
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv.git ~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
and compare with
unzip pyenv-master.zip to ~/.pyenv
unzip pyenv-virtualenv-master.zip to ~/.pyenv
will have some sort of folder

Comment: did that. as I said, zip archives contain a subdirectory from where you need to move files to `.pyenv`

Comment: you're right i make mistake on this, thank you for your help

Comment: no problem and good luck!